# does adding new member function into d pointer class break binary compatibility?

Tags: c++, api-design, binary-compatibility, d-pointer

Will adding new member function into d pointer class definition break binary compatibility?

For example, will the new definition below break binary compatibility compared to the original?  (side question, is there a tool that will tell me if a new .so breaks binary compatibility compared to the old .so?  If not, how do I check manually?)

Original:

```
#ifndef __TESTBC_H__
#define __TESTBC_H__
class APrivate;

class A
{
  public:
   int get() { d->update(); return _d->get(); }

private:
   APrivate *_d;

};

class APrivate
{
  public:
   int get() { return _val; }
   void update() { _val = 1; }

  private:
   int _val;
};
#endif
```

New:

```
#ifndef __TESTBC_H__
#define __TESTBC_H__
class APrivate;

class A
{
  public:
   int get() { _d->update(); return _d->get(); }

private:
   APrivate *_d;

};

class APrivate
{
  public:
   int get() { return _val; }
   void update() { _val = 1; multiply(); }
   void multiply() { _val = _val * 10; }

  private:
   int _val;
};
#endif
```

FYI: I understand d pointer class should be specified in the cc file instead of header.  above example is contrived to focus on binary compatibility issue.

Comment: The tile can be improved...it better clarifies that new function is added to a private class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it does not.

You should understand how C++ builds its objects.

In your case it is just almost "POD" class with non-virtual member functions. These
functions do not affet the representation of object in memory. Thus new version
is binary compatible with old.

More then that, if you do not expose your "APrivate" class to user. (Not giving
a header just forward declaration), you would not brake an API even if you do much bigger
changes.

Meaning:

```
#ifndef YOUR_PUBLIC_API
#define YOUR_PUBLIC_API
class bar;
class foo {
public:
    // member functions using bar
private:
    bar *bar_;
};
#endif
```

You do not even expose `bar` so you may change it in any way you wish. it is the
best way to make C++ libraries ABI compatible.

Comment: I assume ABI, not API. >  "you would not brake an API"

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) tool, it checks header files and shared libs and searches for ABI changes that may break binary compatibility.

Comment: abi-compliance-checker, aka, AbiCC